# pyodbc and RODBC installation issues

Tags: python, r, linux, pyodbc, rodbc

I installed the unixODBC-devel packages via yum.
However, I get an error when I try to install RODBC / pyodbc

RODBC error

> configure: error: "ODBC headers sql.h and sqlext.h not found"

pyodbc error

> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-3ci8Au/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-m83SFn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3ci8Au/pyodbc/

My system is RHEL Linux version 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64. Installed the packages as root. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `unixODBC-devel`, I believe, before you can install RODBC or pyodbc.

```
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel
```

Good luck!